# How to put space in columns while using select in c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle

i want to use space columns while selecting in c# code.in oracle sql developer i can use `select firstname as "first name"` but in c# code i used like `select firstname as [first name]`  but no luck .how to correct it

Comment: If you saw that the SQL worked with double quotes in SQL Developer, why did you expect the SQL to magically work with square brackets in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the double-quotes for it to be valid SQL.

In your C# code you need to escape them, like so:

```
string cmd = "SELECT firstname AS \"first name\" FROM ...";
```

Comment: iirc it was throwing error in my large sql statements.i wl recheck it.Itried starting @ also.let mesee it

Comment: In addition to the answer. Quoted identifiers are case sensitive. By enclosing names in double quotation marks, you can give the following names to different objects in the same namespace: "first name", "First Name", "FIRST NAME".